# Are there any unguided via ferrata routes in the Canadian Rockies?

Tags: canada, via-ferrata

I just learned about the via ferrata route in Banff on Norquay, but if you don't go with a guide then it's considered trespassing. Are there any via ferrata routes in the Canadian Rockies that are open access?

Comment: via ferrata Nordegg can be done without a guide and is open http://www.gravsports-ice.com/icethreads/ubbthreads.php/topics/5475/Via_Ferreta_by_Nordegg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Nordegg](http://www.coe.ca/guiding/ferrata/) has a via ferrata that was set up by COE, the owner Mike Adolph "...recommends anyone using the via ferrata to do so through a guide, [although if a climber shows up with a helmet and the correct harness and clips, they could go solo.](http://www.calgaryherald.com/life/Face+your+fears+plenty+thrills+tackling+ferrata/8612671/story.html)"
2. Mt. Nimbus, BC has a via ferrata run by [CMH](http://www.canadianmountainholidays.com/summer/our-trips/high-flying.aspx). CMH says that ["while the public could, in theory, access Mt Nimbus, it would be difficult."](http://blog.canadianmountainholidays.com/the-adventure/bid/65731/The-Iron-Way-A-Critique-of-the-Mt-Nimbus-Via-Ferrata#ixzz3hJQ983FO)
3. CMH also runs a via ferrata in Bugaboos Provincial Park at Trundle Ridge, which in theory is accessible to anyone, but good luck finding it without a guide (and a helicopter).